# Searching in a collection with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to make a query from an object I have defined that contains a collection. Object looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class ValidationLog {
    @Embeddable
    public static class ValidationLogPK implements Serializable {
        private String dataKey;
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private DataType dataType;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private ValidationLogPK id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ValidationResult validationResult;

    @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<ValidationRule> validationRules;
}
```

And query looks something like this:

```
"select v.id.dataKey from ValidationLog v " + 
    " where v.validationResult = :result" +
    " and v.id.dataType = :type" +
    " and :rule in indices(v.validationRules)"
```

However this does not work. The "indices"-function I am unsure of though. The thing is I would like to get all "dataKeys" that is of a specified type, result and rule. The problem is that each "dataKey" can have many rules as you can see... So how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `MEMBER OF`? Something like this in JPQL:

```
SELECT v.id.dataKey
FROM ValidationLog v
WHERE v.validationResult = :result
  AND v.id.dataType = :type
  AND :rule MEMBER OF v.validationRules
```

If you face [HHH-5209](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5209) (not sure you will, I reported this issue against Hibernate 3.5), try the HQL variant:

```
SELECT v.id.dataKey
FROM ValidationLog v
WHERE v.validationResult = :result
  AND v.id.dataType = :type
  AND :rule IN elements(v.validationRules)
```

**Update:** There is another issue *when using `in elements` on a collection of enums*, namely [HHH-5159](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5159). The problem is not with the query itself, it's with the parameter binding. When using:

```
query.setParameter("rule", ValidationRule.FOO);
```

Hibernate binds a serialized version of the enum (in my case, the query just returns nothing). However, using the following worked for me:

```
query.setParameter("rule", ValidationRule.FOO.name());
```

**Update #2:** I am sorry but I don't think I'll be able to help further. What I posted about the `in element` on a collection of enum works for me when used as suggested with Hibernate 3.4 and HSQLDB. Here is the test:

```
@Test
// http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5159
public void testQueryWithInElementOfCollectionOfElementsOfEnums() {
    Person person = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne");
    Set<SomeEnum> someEnums = new HashSet<SomeEnum>();
    someEnums.add(SomeEnum.ONE);
    someEnums.add(SomeEnum.TWO);
    someEnums.add(SomeEnum.FIVE);

    person.setSomeEnums(someEnums);

    session.persist(person);

    String queryString = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE :someEnum in elements(p.someEnums)";

    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    // query.setParameter("someEnum", SomeEnum.FIVE); // doesn't work, see HHH-5159
    query.setParameter("someEnum", SomeEnum.FIVE.name());
    List actual = query.list();
    assertNotNull(actual);
    assertEquals(1, actual.size());
}
```

And the logs:

```
...
12:40:06.353 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        person0_.id as id11_,
        person0_.dept as dept11_,
        person0_.firstName as firstName11_,
        person0_.gender as gender11_,
        person0_.lastName as lastName11_ 
    from
        Person person0_ 
    where
        ? in (
            select
                someenums1_.element 
            from
                Person_someEnums someenums1_ 
            where
                person0_.id=someenums1_.Person_id
        )
12:40:06.357 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'FIVE' to parameter: 1
12:40:06.359 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
12:40:06.361 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.IntegerType - returning '1' as column: id11_
12:40:06.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.acme.domain.Person#1]
```

Maybe try to simplify the query to narrow down the problem. I'm not sure it's related to the `in element` part.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.6.12 "Collection Member Expressions"
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Comment: It looks like I am getting the same problem as you with the JPQL, MEMBER OF: 

    Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select v.id.dataKey from ValidationLog v  where v.validationResult = :result and v.id.dataType = :type and :rule member of v.validationRules]

Comment: Sadly I get a similar problem with HQL variant also: 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: @Peter Weird, I have a test with the HQL variant i.e. using `in elements()` and it just works (with Hibernate 3.5). I'll test it with Hibernate EM 3.4.

Comment: I tested again and now got a better error:
---
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

---

I am running PostgreSQL and don't know if it is a database specific problem?

Comment: @Peter I think I somehow reproduced the problem, there is something wrong with the binding of an enum parameter (that gets serialized). See my update.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I found that issue also but it dosen't take me all the way, I still get exception: --- Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null [select v from ValidationLog v  where v.id.dataType = :type and v.id.dataKey = ] --- I have checked the generated SQL and it is correct so it looks still looks like something is wrong with the binding of parameters.

Comment: Thanks again Pascal. The last problem I had was a mistake caused by me, so there is no more Hibernate issues.